# Angular: ReferenceError: 'function' is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple [Plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/mT7RTQZhAzxnXeFxKVoi/) app that adds two numbers together on the click of a button.

I am getting a `ReferenceError: addNumber is not defined` where add number is a function that is called by the 'onClick' handler.

```
onClick(num1, num2){
  addNumber(num1, num2).then((result) => this.result = result));
}

addNumber(x, y){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
          x = parseInt(x);
          y = parseInt(y);
          setTimeout(() => resolve(x+y), 2000)
        })
      }
    }
```

However, if I add the `function` keyword to `addNumber` it works but as I understand it, with Typescript it is optional to use the `function` keyword.

Why is addNumber not defined when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing class members you have to reference them using `this`:

```
this.addNumber(num1, num2).then((result) => this.result = result));
```

When you add the `function` keyword to `addNumber` you are making it a local function instead of a class member thus making it accessible without the `this` reference.

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: Didn't see yours. Mine explains why adding `function` before it works.

Comment: I chose this one as the answer because although the solution is the same as @Sajeetharan's, you explain what the problem was

Answer (score 2):

Use  **`this`** for existing class self functions

```
onClick(num1, num2) {
  this.addNumber(num1, num2).then((result) => this.result = result));
}
```